# Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

it use spring mvc with json.I want to get data in json format.Below is the code. I made jsonController.java and Shop.java. But when i run
http://localhost:8080/jsonAPI/rest/kfc/brands
i got error.Can some one tell me  what i need to modify in this code.

**JsonController.java**

```
package com.java;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kfc")
public class JsonController {
    @RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName(name);
        shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"mkyong1", "mkyong2"});

        return shop;

    }

}
```

**Shop.java**

```
public class Shop {
    String name;
    String staffName[];
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String[] getStaffName() {
        return staffName;
    }
    public void setStaffName(String[] staffName) {
        this.staffName = staffName;
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name> 
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
      </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
      </servlet-mapping>

      </web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.java" />

            <mvc:annotation-driven />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" /> 
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
        </bean>
</beans>
```

I got the following error when I am trying to run it:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter] while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:355)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1189)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4935)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:946)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:892)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
        ... 31 more
```

Comment: Looks like incompatible versions of spring and jackson jars. Please show your pom.xml

Comment: i added  jars in lib folder    and the jackson jars  is.....  jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar  ,jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar,  jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar .

Comment: which spring and which jackson jars you have added? Please include the version number

Comment: I tried to write code use that link http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

Comment: Then use the correct version `1.9.10` of jackson. Do you use spring 3.2.2 as in the example?

Comment: I am using spring 3.0.1 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87860/discussion-between-saakshi-aggarwal-and-jens).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to stackoverflow and jens
I used spring 3.2.2 and jackson 1.9.10
Now this issue is resolved

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I deleted the bean that the "ref" property below was pointing to (my bean's id was 'dateObjectMapper').

```
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="dateObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your spring is 4.0 then you use `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`

3.0 use

```
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
```